# complete form text box with data from database table if user exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have asked this Question yesterday. and an expert suggest to me to use Ajax.

please I need to create a button link beside extension number when create form with MVC5. when user enter the extension number, and click the button next to it, then the extension number will passed to JasonResult to search in table. if the extension exist then the textbox form in create view will display his name, location and badge.

here is my controller.

```
  public JsonResult EmployeeInfo(string extension, Ticket ticket)
    {
        var result = from r in db.CUSTOMERS 
                     where r.BADGE_NUMBER == extension
                     select new { r.BADGE_NUMBER, r.LOCATION, r.NAME };

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and here is the code in view.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <input type="submit" id="GetInfo" value="search"/>


            <script type="text/jscript">
                $('#GetInfo').click(function () {
                    $.getJSON('/Tickets/EmployeeInfo/' + $('#Phone').val(), function (data) {

                        $('#rData').html(items);
                    });
                })
            </script>
         </div>
    </div>
```

anyone can help me?
thank you,

Comment: You return `json` not a view, so you cannot use `$('#rData').html(items);` - you need to update the values of your existing elements - e.g. `$(someElement).val(data.LOCATION);` - but its not clear what element you want to update. And remove the `Ticket ticket` parameter from your method.

Comment: And change `type="submit"` to `type="button"` (your not submitting the form)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thank you, I want to return the same create form  with Name, Location and badge filled in textbox ? could you please tell me how to write it in $(someElement).val(data.LOCATION);?

Comment: If you want to return the same form, then you need to return a partial view, not json so its not clear what you really want. I have no idea where in you view you want to display the values you returning. Just add a `<div id="location"></div>` in the view and use `$('#location').text(data.LOCATION);` and you will get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a MVC Controller, which returns a View so this won't work. I would suggest that you add e Web Api controller with a route like this (not tested of course):

```
[Route("Tickets/EmployeeInfo/{extension}")]
public Task<IHttpActionResult> EmployeeInfo(string extension)
{
    var result = from r in db.CUSTOMERS 
                     where r.BADGE_NUMBER == extension
                     select new { r.BADGE_NUMBER, r.LOCATION, r.NAME };

    return result;
}
```

This web api route will deliver your result as JSON. You call this route in the same way you do now with your javascript. 
You should also change your buttons type to button:

```
<input type="submit" id="GetInfo" value="search"/>
```

To

```
<input type="button" id="GetInfo" value="search"/>
```

Comment: `MVC Controller` can return `json` just exactly as OP is doing.